# Reversing an Array: unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to reverse an array with the following code :

```
function reverseArray(array) {
  let newArray = [];
  let tempLast;
  for let value of array {
    tempLast = array.pop();
    newArray.push(tempLast);
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

Basically what I want to do is to take the last value of my array and put it directly inside my newArray.

But I keep getting a "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". This has been bugging me for an hour!
Am I using the wrong syntax with the "for...of" ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: That is invalid syntax. Look up `for` in documentation. Parentheses!

Comment: thank you! now it doesn't take all the elements of the array (forgets the first one), but that is an issue i'll scratch my head on now

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have an intrinsic function "reverse" that will do all of this for you. You can read more about them here. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp

But if you only want to get the last value, it's faster to just grab it by its index... something like `arrayName[arrayName.length -1]`.

```
const addLastToMine = (arrayToAddTo, arrayToGrabFrom) =>
([...arrayToAddTo, arrayToGrabFrom[arrayToGrabFrom.length - 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
x=['a','b','c']
y=[...x]
y.reverse()
console.log(x)
console.log(y)
```

y is a copy of x that gets reversed. x remains not reversed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use correct `for...of` syntax
2. You are not using the `value` in iteration.
3. If you use `push` it will add the element at end, For to make reverse use `unshift` which adds the element at begin.

```js
function reverseArray(array) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let value of array) {
    newArray.unshift(value);
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(reverseArray(['a', 'b', 'c']));
```